# OpenCV: Color disparity maps

Tags: opencv, colors, disparity-mapping

My question is how to color disparity maps like this page: http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I am able to give you just a hint: use the disparity value as Hue in a HSV image, where Saturation and Value are all at maximum. Please answer to your own question if you can come up with working solution, it looks like an interesting feature

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html

Answer (score 1):

Those Disparity map is created using the depth information and u can color the depth map using axis direction.

Also you can create your own method by Building a JetColor Map.

```
 template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
 inline cv::Scalar cvJetColourMat(T v, U vmin, V vmax) {
 cv::Scalar c = cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);  // white
 T dv;

if (v < vmin)
   v = vmin;
if (v > vmax)
   v = vmax;
dv = vmax - vmin;

if (v < (vmin + 0.25 * dv)) {
   c.val[0] = 0;
   c.val[1] = 4 * (v - vmin) / dv;
} else if (v < (vmin + 0.5 * dv)) {
   c.val[0] = 0;
   c.val[2] = 1 + 4 * (vmin + 0.25 * dv - v) / dv;
} else if (v < (vmin + 0.75 * dv)) {
   c.val[0] = 4 * (v - vmin - 0.5 * dv) / dv;
   c.val[2] = 0;
} else {
   c.val[1] = 1 + 4 * (vmin + 0.75 * dv - v) / dv;
   c.val[2] = 0;
}
return(c);
}
```

Note that you can change to other color components incase you need it.